# EF Core ForeignKey-like relationship

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Consider two classes:

```
public class EntA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntityId")]
    public ICollection<TranslationValue> Translations { get; set; }
}
public class EntB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntityId")]
    public ICollection<TranslationValue> Translations { get; set; }
}
```

and then we have the TranslationValue class:

```
public class TranslationValue : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

It all works fine, except one thing: I cannot have foreign key as entries in TranslationValue.EntityId will refer to both EntA and EntB.

So the question is: how do I define the relationship in the exactly same way as above without actually creating a foreign key.

The workaround I am currently using is that I create migration and then delete part responsible for creating actual foreign key.

Comment: `how do I define the relationship in the exactly same way as above without actually creating a foreign key.`- Without foreign how will you set up relationship? it will not be possible.

Comment: Another problem how a single foreign key will map two different table?

Comment: That's why I don't want a foreign key because it is not possible from db side. My point is that when getting EntA or EntB from db EF should fill Translations collection based on EntA/EntB.Id+TranslationValue.EntityId, but I don't need to know which Entity a given translation is for.

Comment: I have understood! But it would not be possible from both EF and SQL server design point of view.

Comment: I don't believe :-) This can be done from relationship side in ef because it works, except that I don't need the foreign key in db.

Comment: Okay then wait for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is: how do I define the relationship in the exactly same way as above without actually creating a foreign key.

Its not possible because how a single foreign key will map to two different table?
Your `TranslationValue` model has to be as follows:

```
public class TranslationValue : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid EntAId { get; set; }
    public Guid EntBId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public EntA EntA {get; set;}
    public EntB EntB {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Okay! Wait! Hope someone will help as exactly as you wanting! :)